# How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, browser-tab

How can I open a new tab in the existing Firefox browser using Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a. Selenium 2) in Java?

Comment: I use java. I got one solution "m_Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");" and its working totally fine.

Comment: Are you then able to control the new tab? Selenium has no support for new tabs (it tries to open new windows instead). See my answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550360/selenium-ide-for-firefox-ctrl-tab/14552367#14552367 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225911/robot-framework-verify-a-new-browser-tab-was-opened/17233198#17233198. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to copy some text and then open a new tab and paste the same text in the new tab. I have not tried to control the new tab but it works fine for what i want to achieve.

Comment: I did the same thing by using GetText() of that element and then did Driver.get(text).

Comment: Do you want to open empty Tab? or, do you want to open a Tab with clicking any link or button?

Comment: Note that the Top 20 or so answers as of now are out of date. I've added an example of WebDrivers new(ish) native tabs below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60731604/4494

Comment: I'll post the link to my previous answer, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72373996/8766115)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The code below will open the link in a new tab.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

The code below will open an empty new tab.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

Comment: use Keys.COMMAND instead of Keys.CONTROL if you are using mac

Comment: This solution seems less-than-optimal since it depends on OS-specific (and perhaps browser-specific) shortcuts... At least, if you use something like JS `window.open()`, you can expect it to work on many platforms/browsers.

Comment: Problem is `window.open()` might open a new window instead of ne tab. It does so on Firefox in test mode. At least when run from Katalon (which uses Selenium under the hood).

Comment: @Nux same for me in Firefox. Is there any workaround for that to open a tab?

Answer (score 99):

Just for anyone else who's looking for an answer in Ruby, Python, and C# bindings (Selenium 2.33.0).

Note that the actual keys to send depend on your OS. For example, Mac uses <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

#### Ruby

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

body = driver.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
body.send_keys(:control, 't')

driver.quit
```

#### Python

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.close()
```

#### C#

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace StackOverflowTests {

    class OpenNewTab {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

            IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you go back to the previous tab?

Comment: WebDriver can handle more than one tab - it simple treats them as seperate windows. So you only need to `driver.switchTo().window(windowName);` to access any tab or window. Obviously, you'd need to keep track of the window name(s) as normal to allow switching between them.

Comment: Could you explain why you're retrieving an element and Sending the Ctrl-t to that element? That doesn't make any sense ... you can't "Ctrl+t on a web element"? Why not just run new Actions(WebDriver)
    .SendKeys(Keys.Control + "w")
    .Perform();      Please could someone explain?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have tried several different ways of pressing ctrl+t, none of which succeed in opening a new tab.

Comment: @Thayne a [ChromeDriver bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=903) prevents CTRL+T from working. You can use CTRL+LMB as a workaround. See https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=903#c2 for sample code.

Comment: Just add the example of python code to use CTRL+LMB. `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(element_to_be_clicked).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`. The *ActionChains* is imported from `selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains`.

Comment: If you need more details about how to use switchTo() - https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: python new grammar: driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "body")

Answer (score 46):

Why not do this

```
driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('your url','_blank');");
```

Comment: most popup blockers will block this attempt

Comment: probably safe for testing where you are in control of your browser settings

Comment: would probably work great. chromedriver seems to disable all extensions(ie. adblock)

Comment: Works great. In chromedriver this is actually opening new tabs for me, which I like better. It's probably because of the settings of my real Chrome.

Comment: The send keys method no longer work for me after updated to Chrome 49.0.2623.75m, and this method works on that Chrome version.

Comment: If you want to open a blank page in the tab, you could `driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank');");`

Comment: The above code shows ExecuteScript- not found symbol. so pls **update** - ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank');");

Answer (score 18):

**To open new tab using JavascriptExecutor,**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Will control on tab as according to index:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Driver control on main tab:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

Comment: How about launching 3 URL's, ? `driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

  driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
  
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(2));
  
  driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
  
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  
  driver.close();
  
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
  
  Thread.sleep(2000);  
  
  driver.close();
  
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));` , I have tried this but getting array out of bound exception, If u know any solution please let me know.

Comment: It work similarly for 3rd tab also. May I know where exactly exception throws(On driver close)?

Comment: No, at this line `driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(2));`, This works fine `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com','_blank');");
  
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.flipkart.com','_blank');");` but I will not have any control to switch to windows.

Answer (score 15):

As of selenium >= 4.0, there is no need for javascript or `send_keys` workarounds. Selenium 4 provides a new API called `newWindow` that lets you create a new window (or tab) and automatically switches to it. Since the new window or tab is created in the same session, it avoids creating a new WebDriver object.

**Python**

**Open new tab**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.window import WindowTypes

driver.switch_to.new_window(WindowTypes.TAB)
```

**Open new window**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.window import WindowTypes

driver.switch_to.new_window(WindowTypes.WINDOW)
```

**Java**

**Open new window**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
// Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
// Opens LambdaTest homepage in the newly opened window
driver.navigate().to("https://www.lambdatest.com/");
```

**Open new tab**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
// Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
// Opens LambdaTest homepage in the newly opened tab
driver.navigate().to("https://www.lambdatest.com/")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code using Java with Selenium WebDriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

By using JavaScript:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // Firefox or any other Driver
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open()");
```

After opening a new tab it needs to switch to that tab:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: The manual operation Ctrl+T to open a new tab has been implemented here

Comment: @ Chandra Shekhar: Can you please try my JS code above?

Answer (score 8):

To open a new window in Chrome Driver.

```
// The script that will will open a new blank window
// If you want to open a link new tab, replace 'about:blank' with a link
String a = "window.open('about:blank','_blank');";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(a);
```

[For switching between tabs, read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java).

Answer (score 7):

### Almost all answers here are out of date.

(Ruby examples)

WebDriver now has support for opening tabs:

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
new_tab = browser.manage.new_window
```

Will open a new tab. Opening a window has actually become the non-standard case:

```
browser.manage.new_window(:window)
```

The tab or window will not automatically be focussed. To switch to it:

```
browser.switch_to.window new_tab
```

Comment: Is this usable with Selenium 4+ only?

The [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#switching-windows-or-tabs)) mention that "Selenium 4 provides a new api NewWindow which creates a new tab (or) new window and automatically switches to it.". I is not entirely obvious from that quote whether opening a new window / tab alone (without automatically switching to it) existed as part of the pre-v4 API.

Comment: Also bare in mind that there are [APIs for getting a handle](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#get-window-handle) to the current window / tab (`original_window = driver.window_handle` in Ruby) before opening the new one, as well as [restoring the focus](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#closing-a-window-or-tab) to the original tab after you are done (`driver.close` followed by a `driver.switch_to.window original_window`).

Answer (score 6):

Try this for the Firefox browser.

```
/*  Open new tab in browser */
public void openNewTab()
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To open a new tab in the existing Chrome browser using Selenium WebDriver you can use this code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");        
string newTabInstance = driver.WindowHandles[driver.WindowHandles.Count-1].ToString();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(newTabInstance);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: Yes this works nice open a new url in same tab of existing url, good for lot's of link tests because it doesn't use a lot of resources.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. How is it different from previous answers?

Answer (score 3):

The below code will open the link in a new window:

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("linkname")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Comment: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'

Comment: @Robino. I see it in Keys class (org.openqa.Selenium)

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble opening a new tab in Google Chrome for a while.

Even `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");` didn't work for me.

I found out that it's not enough that Selenium has focus on driver. Windows also has to have the window in the front.

My solution was to invoke an alert in Chrome that would bring the window to front and then execute the command. Sample code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("alert('Test')");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// To open a new tab in an existing window
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +  "t");
```

Answer (score 1):

How can we open a new, but more importantly, how do we do stuff in that new tab?

Webdriver doesn't add a new WindowHandle for each tab, and only has control of the first tab. So, after selecting a new tab (Control + Tab Number) set .DefaultContent() on the driver to define the visible tab as the one you're going to do work on.

#### Visual Basic

```
Dim driver = New WebDriver("Firefox", BaseUrl)

' Open new tab - send Control T
Dim body As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"))
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t")

' Go to a URL in that tab
driver.GoToUrl("YourURL")


' Assuming you have m tabs open, go to tab n by sending Control + n
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + n.ToString())

' Now set the visible tab as the drivers default content.
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()
```

Comment: Visual Basic? Is it covered by the C# bindings?

Comment: Visual Basic Is covered by Java

Answer (score 1):

I am using Selenium 2.52.0 in Java and Firefox 44.0.2. Unfortunately none of the previous solutions worked for me.

The problem is if I a call driver.getWindowHandles() I always get one single handle. Somehow this makes sense to me as Firefox is a single process and each tab is not a separate process. But maybe I am wrong. Anyhow, I try to write my own solution:

```
// Open a new tab
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");

// URL to open in a new tab
String urlToOpen = "https://url_to_open_in_a_new_tab";

Iterator<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles()
        .iterator();
// I always get handlesSize == 1, regardless how many tabs I have
int handlesSize = driver.getWindowHandles().size();

// I had to grab the original handle
String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.navigate().to(urlToOpen);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
// Close the newly opened tab
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("w").perform();
// Switch back to original
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("1").perform();

// And switch back to the original handle. I am not sure why, but
// it just did not work without this, like it has lost the focus
driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
```

I used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> combination to open a new tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close it, and to switch back to original tab I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (the first tab).

I am aware that mine solution is not perfect or even good and I would also like to switch with driver's switchTo call, but as I wrote it was not possible as I had only one handle. Maybe this will be helpful to someone with the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java for Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

The above code will disable first extensions and using the robot class, a new tab will open.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

Check this complete example to understand how to open multiple tabs and switch between the tabs and at the end close all tabs.

```
public class Tabs {

    WebDriver driver;

    Robot rb;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Anuja.AnujaPC\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://qaautomated.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void openTab() {
        // Open tab 2 using CTRL + T keys.
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

        // Open URL In 2nd tab.
        driver.get("http://www.qaautomated.com/p/contact.html");

        // Call switchToTab() method to switch to the first tab
        switchToTab();

        // Call switchToTab() method to switch to the second tab.
        switchToTab();
    }

    public void switchToTab() {
        // Switching between tabs using CTRL + tab keys.
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");

        // Switch to current selected tab's content.
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeTabs() throws AWTException {
        // Used Robot class to perform ALT + SPACE + 'c' keypress event.
        rb = new Robot();
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    }

}
```

This example is given by [this web page](http://www.qaautomated.com/2017/01/how-to-open-new-tab-with-selenium.html).

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will open a new browser tab using Selenium WebDriver:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("window.open()");
```

Comment: When I ran above code , in chrome its opened a new tab. However in firefox  a new window is opened. In both the cases window handler is different for newly opened ones. So I think a tab is more or less same as a window.  Of course, incognito window is definitely different from regular tab of a window.

Answer (score 1):

#### Java

I recommend using ***`JavascriptExecutor`***:

- Open new blank window:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
```

- Open new window with specific URL:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://google.com')");
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do this. In below example I am doing following steps to open the facebook in new tab,

- Launching `https://google.com`
- Searching for `facebook` text and getting the `facebook` `URL`
- Opening `facebook` in different tab.

**Solution#1**: Using `window handles`.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");
        
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open()");
        
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        
driver.get(facebookUrl);
```

**Solution#2**: By creating new `driver` instance. It's not recommended but it is also a possible way to do this.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");

/*Create an another instance of driver.*/   
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(facebookUrl);
```

**Solution#3: Using Selenium 4**

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook");
String facebookUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')])[1]")).getAttribute("href");
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
driver.navigate().to(facebookUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to open a specific link in a new tab, you can send the shortcut directly to the link like so:

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[strong[.='English']]")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

[Here is an runnable example](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/83a3c257-3b52-4b08-b745-cdd968043622?projectId=examples)

If you need to open a new tab and want to choose which link is opened immediately in said tab, you can use **JavaScriptExecutor** like so:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.wikipedia.org/', '_blank');");
```

[Here is a runnable case that uses JSE](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/e188c510-849c-4234-8957-ea65f89067ed?projectId=examples)

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java) for java, they added a method to create a new tab:

```
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

or a new window:

```
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
```

here is the link to an example on the official [repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/test/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/WindowSwitchingTest.java#L25)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Actions at=new Actions(wd);
 at.moveToElement(we);
 at.contextClick(we).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Comment: In the future, provide some explanation text along with the code snippet to make your posts easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

**To open a new tab in the existing Firefox browser using Selenium WebDriver**

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me right now

Answer (score 0):

The same example for [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js):

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
...
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
                    withCapabilities(capabilities).
                    build();
...
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.COMMAND + "t");
```

Comment: What example? There isn't any example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a bug in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1465 even though webdriver.switchTo actually does switch tabs, the focus is left on the first tab.

You can confirm this by doing a driver.get after the switchWindow and see that the second tab actually go to the new URL and not the original tab.

A workaround for now is what [yardening2 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver/36149226#36149226).
Use JavaScript code to open an alert and then use webdriver to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me (Selenium 3.8.1, chromedriver 2.34.522940, and Chrome 63.0):

```
public void openNewTabInChrome() {

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
    Actions actionOpenLinkInNewTab = new Actions(driver);
    actionOpenLinkInNewTab.moveToElement(element)
            .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL) // MacOS: Keys.COMMAND
            .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(element)
            .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();


    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
    //driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: How can I open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

**Answer**: After a click on any link, open a new tab.

If we want to handle a newly open tab then we have need to handle tab using the .switchTo().window()
command.

Switch to a particular tab, and then perform an operation and switch back to into the parent tab.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Tab_Handle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver_path");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Store all currently open tabs in Available_tabs
        ArrayList<String> Available_tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

        // Click on link to open in new tab
        driver.findElement(By.id("Url_Link")).click();

        // Switch newly open Tab
        driver.switchTo().window(Available_tabs.get(1));

        // Perform some operation on Newly open tab
        // Close newly open tab after performing some operations.
        driver.close();

        // Switch to old(Parent) tab.
        driver.switchTo().window(Available_tabs.get(0));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support opening new tabs. It only supports opening new windows. For all intents and purposes a new window is functionally equivalent to a new tab anyway.

There are various hacks to work around the issue, but they are going to cause you other problems in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the new tab you can use this

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("window.open()");
```

If you want to open the link from the new tab you can use this

**With JavascriptExecutor:**

```
 public void openFromNewTab(WebElement element){
            ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("window.open('"+element.getAttribute("href")+"','_blank');");
        }
```

**With Actions:**

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
                .click(element)
                .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
                .build()
                .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet to open link in new tab:

```
    public void openLinkInNewTab(String link){

    String currentHandle = driver().getWindowHandle();
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver()).executeScript("window.open()");
    //getting all the handles currently available
    Set<String> handles = driver().getWindowHandles();
    for (String actual : handles) {

        if (!actual.equalsIgnoreCase(currentHandle)) {
            //switching to the opened tab
            driver().switchTo().window(actual);

            //opening the URL saved.
            driver.get(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in selenium 4 we have simple way to navigate to new tab         https://medium.com/@vasistatvn/selenium-4-new-features-with-practical-examples-2-a00751c0a978

Answer (score 0):

Java,

Hi you can try the following code for opening a new tab in selenium java.

```
public static void switchToWindow(WebDriver driver) {
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is 8.5 years old and already has nearly 40 answers. Does this answer bring something new that the other answers don't? If so, please explain how it improves upon what is already here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the Control-T keyboard shortcut bug in the selenium driver that was described in a comment above with this simple line of code to execute javascript to open a new tab, then you will have to switch the control to that one.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open();")
```

Here is a simple example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.execute_script("window.open();")
window_after = driver.window_handles[-1]
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely selenium function from Selenium latest version.
Try this if you are working with such specification.

For input, the function requires the current driver employed and current Window Handle string (This is just to make sure you have one window open before going to new tab.).
The return string is for the new Window handle.

```
public static String switchToNewTab(WebDriver driver, String sCurrentWindowHandle) {
    String newTabHandle = null;

    try {
        driver = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        newTabHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newTabHandle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Handling a browser window using Selenium WebDriver:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())  // Switch to new opened window
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);   // Move to previously opened window
```

Comment: Fails to address the question. You answer is about switching to an already existing window, OP asked how to open a new one.