# Open webdriver on a firefox already opened

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am looking for how to open selenium webdriver in a new tab of a firefox already opened. I aim to do that beacause when my java program (webdriver) open firefox, i have to set profile params in my program. To do this, i must every time log on in a dialog frame, because i have installed cntlm.

In short, I want to open firefox in a new tab.

Thaks a lot!

Comment: No.  You cannot use an already-opened Firefox.

Comment: Rather you can use multiple instances of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Please watch [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) Selenium feature ticket for progress.

[Issue 18: Allow webdriver to attach to a running browser](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18)

Your summary `"In short, I want to open firefox in a new tab."` is ambiguous and confusing, if you are looking for how to open new tab, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17547473/1177636).