# Open new tab in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver on Mac

Tags: python, macos, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just installed Selenium Web Driver and tried it out. It works great. My use case can be describe as followed:

1. Start Firefox on a server with pseudo X server (Xvfb)
2. New Driver.Firefox() object
3. Open 10 tabs and load a webpage in each tab
4. Retrieve the html from all loaded pages

The only step that is not working is step 3. I can not find out how to open new tabs. I found this here on SO : [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver) However, I tested this locally (i.e. with visible display) on my Mac for debugging purpose and I saw that the Firefox browser (which was opened when creating the driver object) does not open any tabs when doing as described on the SO thread. So I tried this here:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

As I said, it does not work for me. So, how else is it possible to open tabs? I use Selenium 2.39 (pip install selenium) and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the key combination to open a new tab on OSX is Command+T, so you should use

```
body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

Comment: Yeah, right. However, this is funnily confusing :). Thanks!

Comment: @toom: Just to be clear, it's confusing because Apple made it so, Selenium just follows what's there.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably slightly more correct to send it to the browser via action chaining since you're not actually typing text; this also makes your code more readable imo

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# before correction from  DMfll:
# ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "t").perform()

# correct method
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.COMMAND)‌​‌​.perform()
```

Comment: I wasn't quite getting the expected behavior from `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "t").perform()` . This gave me the expected behavior as documented here: [http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdr‌​iver.common.action_chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdr‌​iver.common.action_chains): `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.COMMAND)‌​.perform()`. It includes a key up and a key down.