# Selenium - Open firefox links in new tabs not new window? Python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Is there any way I can change selenium firefox settings, so whenever i click a button on website that links to another website for example, that link opens in new tab, not new window?

I tried making custom profile, but it never worked for me.. always loads with anonymous one.

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open new tab in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779470/open-new-tab-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver-on-mac)

Comment: Correction; **exact** duplicate :)

Comment: Sorry, I am not looking to paste my links into tabs, i click on button which then opens link in new window, and i want that window to be opened as tab..

Comment: Can't you hold ``CTRL`` key while you "click" the button/link?

Comment: Nothing realy happens if i hold CTRL . I mean its the same as if I tried without CTRL.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to send it via Browser action chaining only as selenium opens an anonymous session everytime. So, send click command like this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "t").perform()
```

Comment: I know about this already, but i cannot get direct link.. I can only click on button which then opens new window, and i want that window to be in tab..