# Cannot open a newtab in selenium webdriver on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I should be able to open a new tab in selenium for python using the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

But no new tab opens, and no error message appears (http://stackoverflow.com/ does load).

Note that I am using `Keys.COMMAND + 't'` because I am running the code on OS X.

I have no idea what is causing the issue as posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779470/open-new-tab-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver-on-mac?rq=1), indicate that my code should work.

**Updated to include answers**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

current_tab = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script('window.open();')
new_tab = [tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab != current_tab][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
driver.get("http://github.com")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user[login]")
inputElement.send_keys('1')

current_tab = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script('window.open();')
new_tab = [tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab != current_tab][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
driver.get("http://github.com")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user[email]")
inputElement.send_keys('2')
```

Comment: Try `driver.execute_script('window.open();')` instead

Comment: @Andersson That worked.... I do not know why. Do you know how to switch to the new open tab. If I can figure that out I will consider the question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to open new tab and switch to it:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

current_tab = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script('window.open("http://github.com");')
new_tab = [tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab != current_tab][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user[login]")
inputElement.send_keys('1')

driver.execute_script('window.open("http://github.com");')
third_tab = [tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab not in (current_tab, new_tab)][0]
driver.switch_to.window(third_tab)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("user[email]")
inputElement.send_keys('2')
```

You can use `driver.close()` to close new tab and `driver.switch_to.window(current_tab)` to switch back to initial tab

Also note that you can pass page `URL` you want to open in new tab as argument to `window.open()` like:

```
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://google.com");')
```

Comment: Very helpful. Just one more question if you look at the update that I posted instead of switching to the newest tab the script instead goes back to the first. I am not sure why it does so.

Comment: When you search for email input field you don't need to switch again and open Github. Check update

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my problem. I am trying to open the same website twice in two different tabs and add text to two different fields.

Comment: Oh... I see. Try `third_tab = [tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab not in (current_tab, new_tab)][0]`

Comment: Works. Excpet that creating a new tab and then loading the webpage need to be two separate commands otherwise it can't find the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to open new tab in MAC:-

```py
String clickOnTabLink = Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "t", Keys.ENTER);
link.sendKeys(clickOnTabLink);
```