# Selenium ActionChains having no effect on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to invoke various keyboard shortcuts but selenium isn't cooperating. I have tried a number of different ways:

Attempt 1:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com")
browser.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'n')
```

Attempt 2: (as above, but selecting a specific element)

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'n')
```

Attempt 3: (using ActionChains):

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "n").perform()
```

Attempt 4: (same as above, but with key_down)

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys("n").perform()
```

I chose to trial "COMMAND n" (new window) because of it's obvious effect. Unfortunately, all of the scripts just go to youtube and then nothing else.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

(Mac, Big Sur, Python3.8)

Comment: Maybe add a key_up after the key down?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374026/cannot-open-a-newtab-in-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-os-x. It is related to open a new tab, not window.. but it might help achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Meant not new browser instance

Comment: I saw that answer, thanks. I haven't tried out running a javascript script. The question is more about figuring out what's going on rather than accomplishing (by any means) taks X. From reading Selenium's documentation the above should work, and the fact that it doesn't is very strange.

Comment: @EdwardGaremo did you figure it out? I am having the same problem on macOS.