# Cannot open a new tab using Firefox WebDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot open a new tab using Firefox WebDriver. I've found a lot of suggestions, e.g. [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-open-a-new-tab-not-a-new-window-and-give-commands-for-carrying-out-tasks-in-each-of-the-tab-in-the-same-browser-using-Selenium-WebDriver-commands), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558909/7550772), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106478/7550772), but they do not work. E.g. none of these worked:

```
ActionChains(driver)\
    .move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body"))\
    .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
    .key_down("t")\
    .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
    .key_up("t") \
    .perform()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

Only this works:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open()")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Can anyone present a better working solution without a need to use JavaScript features?

Comment: What's wrong with JavaScript?

Comment: @Andersson, I am just wondering what I am doing wrong. And it seems that there must be more obvious solution.

Comment: IMHO, `execute_script("window.open()")` is most obvious and efficient solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java scroll through the comments, there are multiple different solutions there (even thought they are in Java, easily converted for your case). from what I see there people are talking about window focus that is needed so send_keys will work.

Comment: See [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python) -- [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python#comment91110223_28432939) explains why ctrl+T doesn't work. There isn't any option