# selenium webdriver golang sendkeys with control

Tags: selenium-webdriver, go

I am trying to open new tab with [selenium webdriver for golang](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver) using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> kyes following [example for another languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558909/1024794). But cannot figure out how to send <kbd>control</kbd>.

My attempts with `"ctrl t"`, `"control t"`, `"Control t"` failed.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fedesog/webdriver"
)

func main() {
    chromeDriver := webdriver.NewChromeDriver("/Users/maks/Downloads/chromedriver")
    err := chromeDriver.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    desired := webdriver.Capabilities{"Platform": "Mac"}
    required := webdriver.Capabilities{}
    session, err := chromeDriver.NewSession(desired, required)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    session.Url("http://stackoverflow.com")
    el, err := session.FindElement("tag name", "body")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = el.SendKeys("ctrl t")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked using the selenium pkg of go.

```
elem.SendKeys(selenium.ControlKey + "a")
```

Browserstack seems to be receiving CONTROLa Perhaps using "CONTROLa" works?
I don't know but selenium works fine so I recommend using it.

Answer (score -2):

You did not tag what language that is, but I'm guessing it's C#

Here's how I accomplish it in java:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

Comment: This post is almost two years old.  While I can see downvoting it based on the question's current content, I am fairly certain that when I answered the question, there was no language tag (I see now there's a go tag) and there was definitely no code shown.  Three downvotes for a correct answer with the caveat that the language was not specified is a tad severe in my opinion.