# Click an alphabet key in watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to open a link in a new tab. I am using watir, watir-webdriver and chrome.
I need to press ctrl + T. How do I do it ?

This does NOT help - 
`browser.element.send_keys [:control, 'T']`

Exception -

```
C:/blah/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keyboard.rb:48:i‌​n assert_modifier': "T" is not a modifier key, expected one of [:control, :shift, :a from C:/blah/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keyboard.rb:25:i‌​n press'....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open a link in a new tab"? If you manually press Ctrl+t on the keyboard, it will simply open a blank tab. If that is your goal, you could have just created a new browser window - ie `browser2 = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`. Perhaps your goal is that when you click on a link, you want it to open in a new tab as opposed to the current tab?

Comment: I could make a new browser, but i prefer to make a tab instead, something like this - browser2 = current_browser.new_tab(tab_name)

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a duplicate. The selenium and watir solutions are identical:

[How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

From the 2nd answer:
`browser.element.send_keys(:control, 't')`

Comment: Also, note, that webdriver won't let you access new tabs, so even if you open it, you won't be able to do anything with it.