# Python selenium use the same window instead of having 3 pop up?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

How do I open the use the same window instead of having 3 pop up?

```
for x in range(3):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1455592987&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fmail.live.com%2fdefault.aspx%3frru%3dinbox&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1455592987&uiflavor=web&uaid=947b22b7c0d249f8ab527df4fb06c828&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1"
```

Comment: If you really need to open 3 tabs in the same window, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
for x in range(3):
    driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1455592987&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fmail.live.com%2fdefault.aspx%3frru%3dinbox&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1455592987&uiflavor=web&uaid=947b22b7c0d249f8ab527df4fb06c828&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1"
```

Or you mean to open 3 tabs in one browser session?