# Selenium IE Driver opens new window instead of a new tab on window.open()

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, selenium

When `window.open()` fires in Selenium IE Web Driver it opens a new window instead of opening in a new tab.

Normally in IE browser it opens a new tab but not in Selenium Web Driver.

Need the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java/27203079#27203079)

you could implement this

```
driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('your url','_blank');");
```