# Unable to open new tab in the same window Chrome, IE browser by using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Open new tab in same window is working in Firefox browser. But it is not working in IE and Chrome.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up cc

Comment: What programming language are you using with Selenium WebDriver? Please provide your code you tried for this.