# How to open link in new tab in selenium webdriver without using find by element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to open new tab in `Firefox` browser using get following is my code that I am using :

```
List<WebElement> url = industries.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for (WebElement e : url) {
   String link = e.getAttribute("href");
   if (null == link)
     link = e.getAttribute("a");
   System.out.println(link);

  driver.get(link);
}
```

Here i am using get because i have already links in list so how i will open new tab in browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19441842/3122133)

Answer (score 1):

For open `link` in new `tab` you should try as below :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

String keys = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);

List<WebElement> url = industries.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for (WebElement e : url) {
    e.sendKeys(keys);
}
```

**Note** :- If you are in **Mac**, need to replace `Keys.CONTROL` to `Keys.COMMAND`

Hope it will help you...:)

Answer (score 1):

use this command to open a new tab on the same browser

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');
```

In your code you can user

```
url.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');
```

Just use this `command` to open a new `tab` on your `browser`.