# C# Chrome with selenium sendkey

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some error with Chrome and Selenium in new tab

I try much of thing to solve it like

```
IWebElement inputBox = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));
        inputBox.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t");
```

and much more like Actions but not work I try it with also chrome v43 also not a good result

anyone know how to open the new tab in Chrome with selenium?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java.

Comment: In Chrome it not work bro

Comment: try with `body` element, `IWebElement inputBox = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
        inputBox.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t");`

Comment: bro its work with firefox but I have a problem in chrome anyway also not work with chrome
Thanks

Comment: Any new help with chrome in selenium :)

Comment: @Qais, Hi there, did you find out how to do this? I am finding the same results. None of the above works. Been digging around stackoverflow for an hour now!

Comment: @Obbles
I used Autoit LIBRARY :)

Comment: haha, actually that's what I ended up doing also. Worked well. For other readers who may read this there are a few things that might hamper the usage of autoit. But here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257548/how-to-get-selenium-to-operate-two-browser-windows-using-only-one-driver-seleniu/52303079#52303079 is a thread that I posted on the matter. There is not yet an answer, but there are some things there I am still working through. It may prove fruitful...