# Python Selenium - Multiple Target Urls

Tags: python, selenium

I wondered if it was possible to query multiple target urls at the same time in Python Selenium. My current code looks like the below which just calls one Url:

Target = 'https://www.skadden.com/professionals?skip=0&position=64063c2e-9576-4f66-91fa-166f4bede9b8&hassearched=true'

My body of code currently works and brings back the data I require. Am I able to call multiple URL's at same time. For example,

Target = ['https://www.skadden.com/professionals?skip=0&position=64063c2e-9576-4f66-91fa-166f4bede9b8&hassearched=true','https://www.skadden.com/professionals?skip=0&position=f1c78f66-a0a6-45e5-8d22-541bd65bb325&hassearched=true']

I have tried this code and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to either start two separate browsers (i.e. request a new session twice) or open two separate tabs as described here: [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)