# How do I open a new tab and without closing the old one in Selenium, retain the previous window

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on 2 URLS . I need to open the first URL ,perform some action and open the second URL.

openURL1()
{
perform action
}

openURL2()
{
perform action
}
switch back to URL1

when I use driver.get or driver.navigate , URL1 gets closed. Is there anyway to retain the window with URL1 while opening URL2?
I am working with selenium and JAVA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: i was asking how do i retain old window and still manage to open a new tab. In my case the previous window gets closed when i open a new one (tab or window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Here is the working code block which opens the URL `http://www.google.com`, prints `Working on Google` on the console, opens `http://facebook.com/` in a new tab, prints `Working on Facebook` in the console, closes the tab which opened the URL `http://facebook.com/`, gets you back to the tab which opened the URL `http://www.google.com` and finally closes it.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    String first_tab = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Working on Google");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
    Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext())
    {

        String next_tab = i1.next();
        if (!first_tab.equalsIgnoreCase(next_tab))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(next_tab);
            System.out.println("Working on Facebook");
            driver.close();
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(first_tab);
    driver.close();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 3):

If the second tab is not opened through an action that is performed in first tab, then you can use two driver objects, so that you'll have control of both the browsers with different driver objects.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://news.ycombinator.com");

    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
    driver1.get("https://www.google.com");
```

By this approach you can use driver to control URL1 and driver1 to control URL2.

Comment: i tried this, but it is still closing the previous window

Comment: it's working fine for me. Is there any action that you are performing on previous window closing the browser ? else, unless you give driver.close the browser won't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use javascript to open new tab

```
(JavascriptExecutor(driver)).executeScript("window.open();");
```

Comment: yes, this worked for me. Thank you. Can you tell me the syntax to add URL to the window

Comment: `(JavascriptExecutor(driver)).executeScript("window.open(your_url_here);");` Also, If this worked, please accept the answer