# Press the CTRL+t keys in the Selenium Python Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

To verify the correctness, I started to press the keys after clicking on the input to see whether they are being clicked.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
elem.send_keys('t')
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).send_keys('ff').perform()
```

The code above will enter into the input tFF, that is, the left shift is clamped. But you should rewrite it to CTRL + t:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
elem.send_keys('t')
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('t').perform()
```

And it does not work, even though it should be logical.

Comment: element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND,  't')

Comment: control + t will open the new tab in browser. Do you want to open new tap?

Comment: See [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python). [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python#comment91110223_28432939) explains why the solution doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To open a new empty tab

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("","_blank");''')
```

To open a url in new tab(say https://www.google.com)

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following,

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
elem.send_keys('t')
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the **CTRL+ T** opens a new tab in Windows machine and even in Mac Machine, no keys are entered in the text box by pressing **CTRL+T**

**If you want to try the other option for sending keys in the text box. It can be:**

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

Comment: I need to open a new tab. When input is active, a new tab can be opened using the CTRL + T. You can check it out.

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer. Please follow the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java