# Error while opening link in new tab using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to save the link in variable `gmail` and trying to open it using send_keys. I'm confused if my declaration of the link is also wrong. It shows type str for declaration.

```
gmail= "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
gmail.send_keys(keys.CONTROL+ Keys.RETURN)**
```

**Type of gmail:**

```
In [319]: type(gmail)
Out[319]: str
```

Please let me know if I can define a link and open it in a new tab in chrome browser driven by selenium.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173275/open-new-tab-in-chrome-from-selenium-web-driver-doesnt-work/46174091#46174091

Comment: Thanks. This was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open an url in a new tab, you can do it this way:

```
gmail = 'http://example.com'
browser.execute_script('window.open("{}","_blank");'.format(gmail))
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

This code will open an url in a new tab. After all you have to close a new tab and go back to previous tab by using this code:

```
browser.close()
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually send_keys will just pass the value in the text field and it will not help you to open the link from it.So it you want to open a link using selenium.

> driver.get("https://google.com")

Likewise you can pass the link so that page will gets open.
if you want to do it in python then

> import requests
>
> requests.get("https://google.com")

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. But I think the question wasn't very clear. I am working in one window using selenium driver and wanted to open my gmail in next tab in same window using driver automatically. Hence I was trying to do what I was doing. If I do what you said, it will just open gmail in place of my currently opened website. I hope I have clarified question now.