# Opening a new tab using Ctrl + click combination in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

I am attempting to use ctrl + click on a link to open it in a new tab. This is working fine in Chrome 58. Please find the code below:

```
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath
("//section[@class='filmStrip__basic']//a[text()='En savoir 
plus']"))).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

I am using the same code on IE, Firefox and Safari but getting the following error:

Firefox 54: The link is getting open in the same tab.
IE 11: Nothing happening.. the control is moving to the next line
Safari: exception on action.keyDown-Unrecognized command

Help related to any one browser is also appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As you are trying to click on a link which is within a `<a>` tag, instead of `xpath` you can use the `linkText` locator. Here is the sample code with opens the url `http://www.google.com`, verifies the `Page Title`, uses `Actions` class to click on the `Gmail` link to open `https://accounts.google.com` in a new tab.

```
String URL="http://www.google.com";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
Actions newTab = new Actions(driver); 
newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

> You can find a relevant *Python* based solution in [How to open a link embed in web element in the main tab, in a new tab of the same window using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730636/how-to-open-a-link-embed-in-web-element-in-the-main-tab-in-a-new-tab-of-the-sam/57733103#57733103)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use javascript executor:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");
```

As for your problem I had it too and didn't find anything usefull until I found this workaround.
I even tried: [solution with ctrl + enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java?rq=1)

Comment: I want to test the functionality of the hyperlink as well. So, need to actually click the link to open it.

Comment: the why not using `click`?

Comment: click is opening it in the same tab. I want to test the entire flow in one go. Thanks

Comment: then just open new tab as above (with the same path) and click on this tab instead of the main, sort of "clone" tab

Answer (score 1):

try this way....

```
// specify chromedriver.exe directory path and replace in "driverPath"

            String driverPath = "C:/Users......";
            WebDriver driver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath + "chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            System.out.println("lanuching 1st url in tab1");

            driver.navigate().to(
                    "https://amazon.com");

            System.out.println("lanuched 1st url in tab1");
            Thread.sleep(30000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "window.open('http://ebay.com');");
            Thread.sleep(20000);
            Set<String> allwh = driver.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(allwh.size());
            for (String v : allwh) {
                System.out.println(v);
                driver.switchTo().window(v);
                String title = driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println("2nd url in tab2" + title);
```