# How to open a link embeded in a webelement with in the main tab, in a new tab of the same window using Control + Click of Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, webdriverwait

There is a link embedded in a web element in the Main Tab, I want to open that link in a new tab in the same window using Selenium Webdriver and python.
Perform some tasks in the new tab and then close that tab and return back to the main tab.
Manually we will do this by right-clicking on the link and then select "open in new tab" to open that link in new tab.

I am new to Selenium. I am using Selenium and BeautifulSoup to web scrape. I only know how to click on a link. I have read through many posts but couldn't find a proper answer

```py
url = "https://www.website.com"
path = r'path_to_chrome_driver'
drive = webdriver.Chrome(path)
drive.implicitly_wait(30)
drive.get(url)
source = drie.page_source

py_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-res-position = '1']")
py_button.click()
```

I expect the link in `div[data-res-position = '1']` to open in a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a link embedded within in the webelement in the *Parent Tab*, to open the *link* in a *New Tab* in the same window using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and *Python* you can use the following solution:

> To demonstrate the workflow the url `https://www.google.com/` was opened in the *Parent Tab* and then `open in new tab` functionalty is implemented through `ActionChains` methods `key_down()`, `click()` and `key_up()` methods.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  import time

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Gmail")))
  ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
  ```
- **Note**: You need to replace `(By.LINK_TEXT, "Gmail")` with your desired locator e.g. `("div[data-res-position = '1']")`
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tab_actions]

> You can find a relevant *Java* based solution in [Opening a new tab using Ctrl + click combination in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201035/opening-a-new-tab-using-ctrl-click-combination-in-selenium-webdriver/46214265#46214265)

---

### Update

To shift Selenium's focus to the newly opened tab you can find a detailed discussion in [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But How do I close the new tab after performing some tasks on it and go back to main tab.

Comment: @Devesh Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Well Sir operations I want to perform are: <br>  1) Open main tab <br>  2) Click on Link embedded in this tab and open it in new tab <br> 3) Switch focus/handle to new tab <br> 5) Perform tasks using BeautifulSoup <br> 6) Close new tab <br> 7) Switch focus/handle to main tab <br> I am done with steps 1,2,5. Could you please help in doing others steps. I checked the  update it didn't work.

Comment: *Update*  I found the solution.     switch_to.window() worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following import:

```
selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

You have to send key:

```
py_button.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I am getting an error "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)"

Comment: Maybe a time.sleep (10) between find_element and send_key

Answer (score 1):

This is trick can be achieve if your locator return a correct `href`.

Try this first:

```
href = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-res-position = '1']").get_attribute("href")
print(href)
```

If you get correct `href`, you can do:

```
#handle current tab
first_tab = driver.window_handles[0]

#open new tab with specific url
driver.execute_script("window.open('" +href +"');")

#hadle new tab
second_tab = driver.window_handles[1]

#switch to second tab
driver.switch_to.window(second_tab)

#switch to first tab
driver.switch_to.window(first_tab)
```

Hope this helps.