# How to right click on a link and open the link in a new tab using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, webdriverwait

I am trying to right click on the *Forgotten account?* link on the Facebook login page using Selenium but it is not working.

I am trying to `send.Keys()` after `contextClick()` but the key press is happening on the page and not on the context menu.

```
package keyboardandmouseaction;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class testcase8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Running keyboardandmouseactions > testcase8");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        WebElement link=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"Forgotten account?\")]"));
        Actions a=new Actions(driver);

        // defective code start
        Action builder=a.moveToElement(link).contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build();
        // defective code end
        builder.perform();



        Set<String> windowid =driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> itr =windowid.iterator();

        String mainwindow=itr.next();
        String childwindow=itr.next();
        System.out.println("The mainwindow id is "+mainwindow);
        System.out.println("The childwindow id is "+childwindow);
        driver.switchTo().window(childwindow);
        driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Alerts.html");
        driver.close();

}
}
```

Comment: `
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).moveToElement(link).click().keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();` modifying the code this opens the link in a new tab but the tab closes instantly and the link is opened in the main tab.

Comment: You need to edit your Question to include all information. Comments are not suited for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
WebElement link=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"Forgotten account?\")]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
        .click(element)
        .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
        .build()
        .perform();

ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *right click* on the link and open the link in a new tab you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and `click()` to open the link in a new tab and finally switch to the new tab using the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Collections;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Control_Click {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
          WebElement forgotPassword = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Forgotten account?")));
          String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("The mainwindow handle is "+driver.getWindowHandle());
          new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(forgotPassword).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          for(String window:driver.getWindowHandles()) {
              if(!parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(window)) {
                  driver.switchTo().window(window);
                  System.out.println("The childwindow id is "+driver.getWindowHandle());
                  driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Alerts.html");
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  The mainwindow handle is CDwindow-0753C465F9132427837081CE5AB8C67D
  The childwindow id is CDwindow-79C688CE476CA8EC4729EFFDE93C84EA
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ctrl_click]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Opening a new tab using Ctrl + click combination in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201035/opening-a-new-tab-using-ctrl-click-combination-in-selenium-webdriver/46214265#46214265)
- [Best way to keep track and iterate through tabs and windows using WindowHandles using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using Java - Selenium and not passing a target URL using MAC

```
WebElement element = find(By.cssSelector ("yourLocator")); 
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver()); 
actions.
    moveToElement(element)
    .keyDown(Keys.COMMAND)
    .click()
    .keyUp(Keys.COMMAND)
    .build()
    .perform();

new WebDriverWait(getDriver(),10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2)); 
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(getDriver().getWindowHandles()); 
getDriver().switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```