# javascriptExecutor Javascript ctrl+click how

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and JavascriptExecutor. I need to make a script/function that ctrl+clicks on an element on a webpage. I know how to make a normal click, `WebDriver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", var)`, but is it possible to ctrl-click (opening a new tab).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: HTMLElement.click() does not have any modifiers, (to my knowledge). What javascript could i write, to ctrl-click the element I have as a parameter in ExecuteScript().

Comment: Try to use `var.sendKeys(Key.Control)` before clicking it or construct your own click event and dispatch it to the element.

Comment: @PeterBandsholm Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201035/opening-a-new-tab-using-ctrl-click-combination-in-selenium-webdriver/46214265#46214265) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730636/how-to-open-a-link-embeded-in-a-webelement-with-in-the-main-tab-in-a-new-tab-of/57733103#57733103) discussion help you?

Comment: @DebanjanB unfortunately no.. it has to be javascript code, called by JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: Why you should only use javascript? There's no a reliable way to simulate a key press in JS for security reasons.