# How to click a link within an iFrame which opens a new tab and switch to it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am working on a project which includes clicking on a link and that should open in a new tab using webdriver, the problem is

1. The supposed link is contained in iFrame, so`shift+click` isn't working

   ```
   private void openInNewTabAndSwitch(WebElement linkElement) {
   // logic of opening in new tab goes here...
   Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
   newTab.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(linkElement).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
   Set<String> windowSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
   driver.switchTo().window((String) windowSet.toArray()[1]); }
   ```
2. I cannot find the `href` attribute since some javascript function is opening it using some `onClick()`

```html
<a onclick="javascript:LinkOccam (this, 'opportunity');">Mednomics Proposition</a>
```

**Problem:-**
It simply opens the required page in same tab.

Now, I cannot find anything related to this, please help..!

**Other related info**
I am using windows 7, Java 8, ChromeDriver

Comment: `shift+click` code trials and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: What's wrong with `WebElement.click();`?

Comment: That doesnt open in new tab, I need it to be opened in new tab

Comment: try `Ctrl + Click` for new tab

Comment: Sorry, ctrl+click isnt working

Comment: what is the error. please update your question with error

Comment: what is your environment? os, browser, drivers version and bit version etc.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19441842/2575259

Comment: It shows "Cannot focus element"

Answer (score 0):

While you click on a *WebElement* which opens a *New TAB* you don't need to worry about whether the *WebElement* is on *Top-Level Browsing Context* or within an  *iFrame*. Additionally while switching the *TAB* induce *WebDriverWait* and switch accordingly. To achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
private void openInNewTabAndSwitch(WebElement linkElement) 
{
    String parentTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
    newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(linkElement).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
    Set<String> windowSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String tab:windowSet)
    {
        if(!parentTab.equalsIgnoreCase(tab))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(tab);
            //do your work in the newly opened TAB
        }
    }
}
```