# How to open the link in new tab Selenium UI automation test C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing the selenium UI tests. I need to open the link in new tab after I click the URL. I used the below code but didn't work.

```
Actions action = new Actions(WebDriver);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(TermsOfUseLinkElement).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver). It's java and not C#, but the selenium wrapper is almost the same in most languages, so you should be able to make working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

```
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)WebDriver).ExecuteScript("window.open('" + TermsOfUseLinkElement + "','_blank');");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to stick with `Actions` you can use the following solution:

```
Actions action = new Actions(WebDriver);
action.keyDown(Keys.Control).Click(TermsOfUseLinkElement).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: I tried this one. But If i am hitting the multiple links, this was not working.

Comment: @AshokYaganti In the question heading/description you mentioned about `open the link in new tab`, your code trials is for a single link, from where does **hitting the multiple links** comes from? Can you shed some light?