# how to open new tab in selenium webdriver using Java or how to press ctrl +T in selenium using action class using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

how can I press CTRL+T in Selenium Webdriver using Java.
Or
how to open new tab in selenium webdriver using Java.

[Simple steps:
1. open google.com [do not have to touch any element/link of the page]
2. open new tab
3. open yahoo.com

I have tried action class but its not working

```
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Here, there is link . Where user has to click on link and go to the new browser. But here in one tab / open google.com. dont do anything. And open new tab / in that open yahoo.com

Comment: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver> for a detailed explaination about this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with javascript and robot class. Hope this will help you..

**JavaScript**

```
   driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   //Open new tab
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   jse.executeScript("window.open()");

   //Switch to new tab 
   ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
   driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
   driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

**Robot Class**

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    //Robot Class
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

    //Switch to new tab
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works me:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        String a = "window.open('https://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');";
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(a);
```