# Opening URL's on same browser in different tab from CSV in Python

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I am trying to open a list of URLs in new tabs in a single window, but it instead opens them in new windows. Please help. This is my `URL.csv`

```
SN,Title,URL
1,Google,https://google.com
2,youtube,https://youtube.com
```

---

```
import csv

from selenium import webdriver


def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')

    for line in reader:
        url = line["URL"]
        title = line["Title"]
        print(url + title)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
        driver.get(url)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("URL.csv") as url_obj:
        csv_url_reader(url_obj)
```

Comment: Using javascript and robot class ...you can run open new tab ... I run this script in java .. but for logic you can refer this code .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005236/4513879

Answer (score 1):

In the piece of code that you posted you are opening the URL in the driver instance and not a new tab.

Instead, you should try opening new tabs like this:

```
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')


    for line in reader:
        url = line["URL"]
        title = line["Title"]
        print(url + title)
        driver.execute_script("window.open(" + url + ",'_blank');")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("URL.csv") as url_obj:
        csv_url_reader(url_obj)
```

Comment: Its just opening a blank page.Not any Urls Thanks.

Comment: Did you format the actual url query? Try now, just edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you put `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')` inside the loop, you are creating a new webdriver instance for each website.

Try something like this:

```
import csv
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')

    for line in reader:
        url = line["URL"]
        title = line["Title"]
        print(url + title)
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
        driver.get(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("URL.csv") as url_obj:
        csv_url_reader(url_obj)
    time.sleep(9999999)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur concern bro.Now what is happening that it opens a browser with google.com and instead of opening a new tab on the same tab its opening youtube.com and after that the browser closes.What i want is that it opens google.com in 1st tab and in 2nd tab it open youtube.com and remains open.

Comment: Yep, my mistake! Try this: `driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{url}","_blank");''')` instead of `driver.find_element_by_tag_name` and `driver.get(url)`. If you need to close the first blank window, try switching between tabs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium)

Comment: its still not working man .In a flick of seconds the browser is closing

Comment: Well, can you please define what you want to do after you open these pages?

Comment: I want to open multiple urls on different tab on a single browser.even if i add more urls in my csv.i want the browser to remain open after loading the links.thanks.

Comment: Bro everything is working fine all links are opening but on the same tab,It does not open different tabs.It just load each link on the same tab.Seems this driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')   Is not working anyhow.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new tab you would use
`send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')` for mac,
or
`send_keys(Keys.CTRL + 't')` for windows

Comment: It's not opening a new tab instead it opens the second link on the same tab