# How do I use the search bar with selenium? Including, duplicating a tab in the Firefox webdriver

Tags: python

So, I need to make a program that will allow the user thirty seconds to find a page on the website in the FireFox Web driver. Once it has found the page, it will loop multiple times, duplicating the tab that was just open. If this doesn't work, I can copy and paste the link into the search bar.
I do not want to create a new window, or open a new Firefox webbrowser!

Comment: There are quite a few ideas in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Can I have some please?

Comment: Have you tried any code at all? I suggest you search for the word firefox in the SO discussion I cited then try a few.