# Creating New Tabs and Managing Them - Selenium

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my Code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
_driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

It will open an instance of chromedriver.exe and will navigate to the target URL.
I need to navigate to other URLs with the same chromedriver.exe intance, and I need to set specific headers and cookies for each URL.

How to achieve something with Selenium and ChromeDriver?

Comment: Please remove the `winforms` tag, as this has nothing to do with desktop apps.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, i;d do this with multiple browser instances. They shouldn't leak state between them and it makes start up, cleandown and management much easier.

However - if you must use tabs, something like this would help...

This is a simple manager:

```
  class BrowserManager
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
   
        public BrowserManager()
        {
            //do your browser options here
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        }

        public IWebDriver getDriver()
        {
            return driver;
        }

        public void addTab(string url)
        {
            var js = $"window.open('{url}','_blank');";
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js);

            var handles = driver.WindowHandles.ToArray<string>();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles[handles.Length -1]); //switch to latest tab
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        public void activateTabForPartialURL(string url)
        {
            var handles = driver.WindowHandles;
            foreach (var handle in handles)
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
                if (driver.Url.Contains(url))
                    return;
            }
        }

    }
```

This is how you use it.
Plenty more ways to find the tabs you want, this is just a quick example

```
    class UsingTheBrowserManager
    {
        [Test]
        public void usingIt()
        {
            string google = "https://www.google.com";
            string stackoverflow = "https://stackoverflow.com";

            var browserManager = new BrowserManager();
            var driver = browserManager.getDriver();

            //create all your drivers:
            browserManager.addTab(google);
            browserManager.addTab(stackoverflow);

            //Do your  cookie/header work 
            //...

            //pick and tab and doing an action or get some data
           browserManager.activateTabForPartialURL("google");
            Debug.WriteLine(browserManager.getDriver().Title);

            browserManager.activateTabForPartialURL("stackoverflow");
            Debug.WriteLine(browserManager.getDriver().Title);

        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you man, looks great. will test it soon. as another sub-question do you know how to add headers before navigating to a URL? and do you know how to fetch response headers and some other data after navigating? If yes I open a new question for them :)