# How to open a new tab in the same chrome browser window using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I know how to open a new window using selenium. But I want a new tab in the same window of chrome which I am using. How to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Actually, what I want is that wen we open new sites in browser, we have already been logged in that site and there is no need to login to eery website which we open. But when I use selenium's driver.get(url) it open in a new window where I have to login to that site again. This makes the whole automation process very tedius. So I am looking for its solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood the issue, but it seem that you might need to [save/use cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) for following web-navigation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open particular element in newtab  use below code segment

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
// your element 
        WebElement newtab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
        newtab.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

Comment: this is in java you can change it to python