# Opening a new browser tab

Tags: selenium, go

I've tried several functions but none seems to be working? For example:

```
element, _ := webdriver.FindElement(selenium.ByCSSSelector, "body")
element.SendKeys(selenium.ControlKey + "t")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is capable of executing javascript within the browser.

To open a new tab get selenium to run the following:

```
window.open()
```

I've not used Selenium & Go before - so I can't comment on the syntax. However it's normally along the lines of `driver.ExecuteScript("window.open()")`. See if your IDE will help you plug the gap.

After you get a new tab, you typically need to use the `.switchTo` in order to move selenium to another tab.

---

updated:

Docs suggest....

```
// ExecuteScript executes a script.
    ExecuteScript(script string, args []interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

see [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tebeka/selenium#WebDriver.ExecuteScript)