# How to command click (open in new tab) in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an array of `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`s. In order to loop through theses elements and keep the session, I need to open each element in a new tab, extract the data, then close the tab. I see THAT there is a way to open a new tab, but it requires a url: [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java) . Is there any way to command click these elements?

SOURCE: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

```
    def click(self) -> None:
        """Clicks the element."""
        self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a new tab with selenium you can send <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keys in Windows OS.
Tab can be closed with <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> keys on Windows OS.
Like this:

```
#open tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

For OSX <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> can be used accordingly.

Comment: This is the correct answer... as a sidenote sometimes dataframes prevent you from opening a new tab

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Selenium 4 and later versions.
try this code

```
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(linkURL)
```