# How can i same session id in my test when i close single open tab in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want run one test script. The scenario is like that;

- Go to login page
- Login with valid credentials
- Close current single tab
- Go to the login page again
- Verify whether browser will go homepage instead of login page or not.

But i don't know how can i do that. Because if i use close or quit method, session id will be killed. even if i open new browser for another step, it will not be same with real scenario. Because as manually, if i try to go to login page after closing single open homepage without logging out, i can go to home page directly. I am not be able to automate it.

I used some Actions method to close and also open new tab.
And i used these;

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(“body”)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+”t”);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(“body”)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w');

I am using Selenium+Java+Cucumber+Chrome+Mac

Comment: From Selenium 4+, there is a `newWindow` method that let you open said window as a tab or a separate window. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640852/10621296

Comment: I know but i am not using selenium 4+ in my framework and i am not able to change it. That's why i should find different solution.

Comment: Then please add what version of Selenium you are using. Since Selenium 4 and newer releases already have solutions for this, knowing which version of Selenium you have can help others better understand your problem.

Comment: My Selenium version is 3.141.59. And also i am using Singleton and POM design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use profile to achieve this scenario. I 've just given some sample code:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Temp\\");
    options.addArguments("--profile-directory=ChromeData");
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2IX_2- VJZDxU']")).sendKeys("<username>");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2IX_2- _3mctLh VJZDxU']")).sendKeys("<password>");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2HKlqd _3AWRsL']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.close();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
```

The above code will create a new chrome profile in the directory - "C:\Temp\ChromeData", then open the browser, launch the URL, login, close the window, again open a chrome browser, launch the same URL, but this time, the user already logged in.

Comment: How can apply this code for Singleton design pattern?

Comment: This is the different question.

Comment: Maybe, but the problem is this. I think, this problem can be disadvantages of singleton.

Comment: After closing the window, make driver as null, then continue